# Django, how do I split up a model's column into three text fields?

Tags: python, django, textfield

I have an issue with splitting up a column in a model into three separate text fields.

Right now, I have this:

```
class Software(models.Model):

    version = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

And, then in the admin panel, for the program's version, you get one text field.

So, if you have a version like this: 1.2.3

I want a text box for 1, another for 2, and the last one for 3.

So, it might look like this:

|1|.|2|.|3|

Then, when I get the values of all three text fields,

I will combine them to make this string: '1.2.3'

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make 3 different fields. Actually probably 4.

```
version = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
major= models.IntegerField()
minor = models.IntegerField()
patch = models.IntegerField()
```

Then use a pre/post_save signal to populate your version field:

```
def pre_save_software_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.version = "{}.{}.{}".format(instance.major,
                                         instance.minor,
                                         instance.patch)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_software_reciever, sender=Software)
```

Then in you'll need to format your form to make it look as you described.

Alternatively, you could create three form fields and create a validate function that populates the version, but IMO it's always best not to multipurpose one field. If you ever forsee yourself needing or reporting on any of the Major/Minor/Patch parts it will be much more straight forward with them all saved seperately.